# Where clause and how it it is bound to others

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'll start off with an apology because i really do not know how to give a title to this question. If any editor can think of a better title, please go ahead and edit this.

Problem Description:
I started out trying to find a solution to select top 2 values from each group. As usual the answer is found on stackoverflow, but I can't quite make sense out of the query that works for me.

It is a table with [id][name][score] columns, and the query selects the top 2 scores for each person.

Here is the query

```
SELECT *
FROM   ScoreTable s
WHERE 
        (
            SELECT  COUNT(*) 
            FROM    ScoreTable  f
            WHERE f.name = s.name AND 
                  f.score >= s.score
        ) <= 2
```

There is something implicit going on here, and I would appreciate a rough trace of what sql engine did to populate the results?

----------- Supplement codes to create table and insert data (SQL SERVER)------

```
use TestDB;

CREATE TABLE ScoreTable(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [score] [int] NOT NULL
) 
insert into ScoreTable values('A', 81)
insert into ScoreTable values('A', 82)
insert into ScoreTable values('A', 83)
insert into ScoreTable values('A', 84)
insert into ScoreTable values('B', 85)
insert into ScoreTable values('B', 86)
insert into ScoreTable values('B', 87)
insert into ScoreTable values('B', 88)
insert into ScoreTable values('C', 89)
insert into ScoreTable values('C', 90)
insert into ScoreTable values('C', 91)
insert into ScoreTable values('C', 92)
```

Comment: you reference both mysql and SQL Server.  please specify which one you mean;  they are not the same thing.

Comment: @nomistic  i naively thought that there is a generic sql soluntion to both mysql and sql-server. I am running sql server, and the solution is found in a mysql thread, hence my assumption. I added more tags to attract more viewers

Comment: please delete the incorrect one.  Your code will not work with mysql.

Comment: @nomistic: Why do you think it's not working in mysql? This is the most generic SQL to do a ranking.

Comment: the format for your table creation is incorrect

Comment: @nomistic: The create table is different, but the query is still working in both MS SQL and MySQL (and probably any other DBMS)

Comment: @dnoeth yes that is correct. The queries will work in most versions of SQL.   I didn't feel like correcting the syntax to build it in my test database.

Comment: (note, your response is what the OP is asking for)

Answer (score 2):

Logically it's similar to following steps:

First you do a self-join with non-equality:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ScoreTable s
JOIN ScoreTable  f
  ON f.name = s.name AND 
     f.score >= s.score
```

You will notice that this will greatly increase the number of rows.

Then you do a GROUP BY to count the number of rows, i.e. the rank:

```
SELECT s.name, s.score, count(*)
FROM   ScoreTable s
JOIN ScoreTable  f
  ON f.name = s.name AND 
     f.score >= s.score
GROUP BY s.name, s.score
```

Finally you filter for the requested rank:

```
SELECT s.name, s.score, count(*)
FROM   ScoreTable s
JOIN ScoreTable  f
  ON f.name = s.name AND 
     f.score >= s.score
GROUP BY s.name, s.score
HAVING count(*) <= 2
```

If name/score is not a unique combination it's a bit more complicated to calculate a ranking.

Because this processing is expensive and not efficient, most DBMSes (like MS SQL, but not MySQL) support Windowed Aggregate Functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
   SELECT name, score, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY score DESC) as rnk
   FROM   ScoreTable
 ) as dt
WHERE rank <= 2
```

Comment: hi dnoeth, thanks for the rapid reply. I noticed it immediately after you replied, and was trying to understand your response. In the section where you filter for requested rank, I tried running the code against my db. It is not working for me.

Comment: @Ji_in_coding, what version of SQL Server are you using.  Old versions may not support windowing functions.

Comment: i did not test the windowing version of the code. I meant the code that has "having" clause doesn't work for me.. I am running both sql2008R2 and sql2012, I believe the windowing function should work.

Comment: I forgot to add the score to the GROUP BY, fixed.